# How do you encode a response in binary in http.server

Tags: python, http, server

I am trying to make it so that you can send binary data (like images) using http.server on Python. When It tries to send a image or video file, it gives an error.

I tried to encode it using binary, but that didn't work. Here is my code at the moment:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time
import os.path
import mimetypes

config = open("config.txt", "r")
configlist = config.read().split("__")

hostName = "0.0.0.0"
serverPort = "8080"

class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == "/":
          mp = open("srvf/index.html", "r")
          self.send_response(200)
          self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
          self.end_headers()
          self.wfile.write(bytes(mp.read(), "utf-8"))
        elif os.path.exists("srvf" + self.path):
          f = open("srvf" + self.path, "r")
          f2 = f.read()
          self.send_response(200)
          self.send_header("Content-type", str(mimetypes.guess_type(self.path)))
          self.end_headers()
          self.wfile.write(bytes(str(f2), "utf-8"))
        else:
          a = open("error.html", "r")
          a2 = a.read()
          self.send_response(404)
          self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
          self.end_headers()
          self.wfile.write(bytes(a2, "utf-8"))
          print("error 404 on " + self.path)
if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, int(serverPort)), MyServer)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")
```

Also, the error is:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 71: invalid continuation byte.

Comment: and what is the error ? please [edit] and provide everything about the error you have

Comment: You haven't share the full stacktrace, we don't know which lines raised the error